# PHPStorm complains on simple use of array variables

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, phpstorm

Anyone know how to fix "Simple use of array variables" in BASH?

for instance:

```
# will complain $paths[@] is a simple array variable
for path in "${paths[@]}"; do 
    [ ! -d "${path}" ] && mkdir -p "${path}"
done
```

I have about 10 notices in my code I would like to take care of

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like a [bug in bashsupport](https://code.google.com/p/bashsupport/issues/detail?id=95&q=array) for IDEA / PHPStorm / etc.

It seems that the code [only checks for arithmetic expressions between the brackets](https://code.google.com/p/bashsupport/source/browse/bashsupport/src/com/ansorgit/plugins/bash/lang/psi/impl/vars/BashVarImpl.java#130), so
`paths[1+2]` works but `paths[@]` does not as it is no arithmetic expression.